# How to prevent PostBack without using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp button in `default.aspx`:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

And there is a procedure in `default.aspx.vb`:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Panel1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(Date.Now))
End Sub
```

And teacher asked me, how to make exactly same operation (when click on button, shows up a date) but without postback and without javascript code. I could make a java code there and use `OnClientClick="return false"` but it seems not right

Comment: You teacher wants something to happen without writing code (server-side or client-side) :?

Comment: Use partial rendering in `update panel`. Check this for sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx

Comment: @Pratik That uses javascript.

Comment: @Curt Completely agree but it's just another suggestion as there is no manual javascript coding as its internally generated. In true sense `without postback` and `without javascript` Adarsh comments works.

Comment: UpdatePanel will not only use JavaScript, but will also do a postback using Ajax to get the updated content for the panel. Maybe it's what the teacher wants - but it's not really true that no postback or JS is used.

Comment: @becquerel yep, that is what he wanted to hear from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer **[The Client Side of ASP.Net Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163512.aspx)**

**You can't do.** The default behaviour of Button(input type=submit) is to `submit/post` the form to the url specified in the form's `action` attribute.

If you want to prevent default behaviour you need to write a javascript `return false`

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" OnClientClick="return false" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

By Default asp.net post the form to the same page itself. We say this as PostBack. See the form tags action value from rendered html in browser , it will be the same page name

```
<input type =submit name ="btn" id="btn" 
  onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('btn','')"value ="Button">
```

The following built in javascript code does this

```
<script>
                   function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
                       document.Form1.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
                       document.Form1.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
                       document.Form1.submit();
                   }
</script>
```

Your page will have the below fields added automatically, inorder to detect which event needs to be fired in server side. you can access simply in a request parameters like `Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"]`

```
<input type =hidden name ="__EVENTTARGET" value ="">
<input type =hidden name ="__EVENTARGUMENT" value ="">
```

Comment: Or just `<input type='button' />`

Comment: what about scriptmanager and updatepanel? Can I use them to prevent postback?

Comment: @JohnSmith Updatepanel internally uses ajax for postback so `no postback` is not possible